# Time Zone set in automation through soap api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, timezone, schedule

I created Scheduled automation through soap api. but i am not getting current time zone. I used particular time zone with below code but automation taking default time zone than how to set particular time zone for Scheduled auomation.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181"
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>User123@sfdc.com</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">TEst123</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ScheduleRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">    
        <Action>start</Action>
        <Schedule>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Recurrence xsi:type="q1:DailyRecurrence" xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>Interval</q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>
                <q1:DayInterval>1</q1:DayInterval>
            </Recurrence>
            <RecurrenceType>Daily</RecurrenceType>
            <RecurrenceRangeType>EndAfter</RecurrenceRangeType>
           <StartDateTime>2018-02-27T09:00:00-06:30</StartDateTime>
            <TimeZone>(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi</TimeZone>

            <Occurrences>1</Occurrences>
        </Schedule>
        <Interactions>
            <Interaction xsi:type="q2:Automation" xmlns:q2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <q2:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <q2:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <q2:CustomerKey>ea5cb858-80fa-dd28-b3c3-d182682d9c4e</q2:CustomerKey>
            </Interaction>
        </Interactions>
    </ScheduleRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Hi all Just now i got the answer above question please check  below code and use in time zone.
-------------
-------------
<TimeZone>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ID>34</ID>
                   <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                   <Name>(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi</Name>
                     </TimeZone>

Answer (score 0):

Timezone value is an int. The Marketing Cloud API has more information about [TimeZone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/timezone.htm):

> ### Available Time Zones
>
> A Retrieve call on this object returns a list of all available time zones.
>
> 1 (GMT-06:00) Central Standard Time
>   2 (GMT) Casablanca
>   3 (GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
>   4 (GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik
>   ...

Comment: Please don't just add a link. If this link answers the question, add some relevant content as well.